# Recreating Standard Google Map embed with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

So, having been recently somewhat dissapointed with lack of customizability of the regular google maps "embed" (iframe) code; I have started tinkering with the Google Maps API v3.  Really, all I want to do is show a marker for a business on the map, so that you can click it and go to that "place" at mapsgoogle.com.

So pretty much, I just want to recreate the functionality of the iframe code below.  I put in about an hour of reading the docs, but it seems extremely complicated just to get the marker associated with a 'place'

**The place**

https://maps.google.com/maps?cid=1311411133662139490

**The *standard* Embed**

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?cid=1311411133662139490&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=41.097905,-73.405006&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?cid=1311411133662139490&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=&amp;t=m&amp;iwloc=A&amp;ll=41.097905,-73.405006&amp;spn=0.006295,0.006295&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
```

It appears as though there is no functionality in the api to use the `cid`.

**To Elaborate a little**

Generally I would use this just for small business websites.  I was frustrated with the regular iframe embed and lack of customizability.  Essentially I want a starting point from which I can play with stuff and heavily customize the look/feel, but have been unable to put a marker in that's associated with the data for a "place" - allowing for the little pop-up window, etc..

Honestly, I didn't really do enough research before asking this question - and came in with some misconceptions.  *I think*, and I may be wrong, that the API is still what I want to be using ultimately, but had I know about the functionality in Rick's answer, I probably would have settled on that and procrastinated longer on learning the gmaps API.

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly the functionality of your web app is supposed to be? from my understanding I assume you want a map that has a marker on it, which includes an infoWindow that has similar information as the one in the iframe..and i'm guessing if you click on the title you want the application to open up the actual google maps service with that location?

Comment: I see, indeed this can be achieved with Google Maps API. You may have to use other services in google maps, like the geocoder service. But this is all things you'll have to experiment with and, like you said, play around with. I'll put something together in a jsFiddle and give you some resources to refer to - sometime today. You'll find it is very customizable and that there's always an option/functionality in the API that will do what you want. In the meantime, I think this would be a great starting point: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#AddingOverlays

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Allow me to explain one option of achieving your goal. I use the marker and infoWindow objects that Google Maps API v3 offers, which you can find in the document I attached in the link. Feel free to follow along in the jsFiddle I created: http://jsfiddle.net/bgvYH/

First thing is first, you want to initiate your map with its options - I'm going to assume you know what the different variables in following code snippet represent:

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.097905,-73.405006);
  var myOptions = {
  zoom: 16,
  center: myLatlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

If you want to customize your map even more to your liking, have a look at the different options you can set in the API reference, you'll set these options in the myOptions object ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions ).
Note: I set the center of the map to the Lat/Long coordinates of the restaurant - which I took from the URL you provided in the iframe `ll=41.097905,-73.405006`.

Now what you want to do next is determine the content you want to display in your infoWindow, so the restaurant information:

```
var contentString = "<div id='content'>";
    contentString += "<div id='title'>Mr. Frosty's Deli and Grill</div>";
    contentString += "<div id='info'><p>10 1st Street</p><p>Norwalk, CT 06855</p><p>(203) 956-5767</p><p><a href='http://thebeachburger.com/'>thebeachburger.com‎</a></p></div></div>";
```

You may even end up pulling this information from a database or JSON object in the future, depending on how deep you go into this project (for now I have it as static HTML).

Next we initialize the infoWindow object and set the contentString to the content option of the infoWindow. There are other options you can customize here (just like the map options, again look at the reference for InfoWindowOptions: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions )

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
```

After setting up your infoWindow object, you initialize your marker object - which will place the drop the bubble on the map. Once again, you set up the options for the marker when initializing much like you did with the map object and the infoWindow object - you can further customize it to your liking by looking at the reference (I think there's even an option in there for the marker where you can use custom icons - you can get pretty creative here).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  title:"Mr. Frosty's Deli and Grill"
});
```

And finally, you need to bind the Marker and the infoWindow together - so that when a user clicks on the marker the info pops up. This is achieved by using the event listener, and you listen for a "click" action on the marker variable. Read this document for information on events on google maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events. Likewise look through the API Reference for the different events you can listen to on an object.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

That should do it, you should have a working alternative to the iframe you include - except now you can customize the map and the actions you perform on it to however you want. In the jsFiddle I also included some styling, just to make things look nice inside the infoWindow.

---

Now, I want to let you know - I believe there is another option to what your looking for - but I have yet to experiment with this API. It is the Google Places API, which you'll have register for. But from what I read through the documents, I think you may be able to achieve what you want to do. Have a look at it ( https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ ), and see what's good.

Comment: Wow that is one awesome and thorough answer!  I don't think I'll even have time to fully go through it until the weekend. Thank you though!

Comment: That is quite strange indeed, seems like the map is getting initialized twice. How are you loading in your js scripts? From looking at the code with chrome's dev tools I think your using modules - correct me if I'm wrong? But I see where you initialize the map with a MapTypeId of HYBRID (which is satellite imagery with the street labels). But I'm also seeing a callback to the initialize function in a document ready jquery function. My guess would be to get rid of that callback, instead include your initialize function inside the document ready one.

Comment: Quite difficult to troubleshoot if you don't give me any js to work with, but looking through with the dev tools - that is my best guess. I apologize in advance if it doesn't help.

Comment: Ah thank you, very helpful - I think there is old code floating about from when I was trying stuff and abandoned it.  Sorry to waste your time

Comment: No worries, if you run into any obstacles even after tidying up the code feel free to post your queries here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was created through 'My Places' and made public. If you don't want to mess with the API then that's your best bet.

Visit maps.google.com, click 'My Places' and 'Create Map'. Customize and grab the embed code.

Comment: wow - I had no idea that existed.  This is probably what I want.  I have to tinker a bit, but unless someone really wows me, u might be gettin' them points!

Answer (score 0):

If the map doesn't need to be interactive (beyond the click action), use [a static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/imageapis/). It's just an image so you can wrap it in an anchor that points exactly where you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chad.  I'm really hoping to get the functionality where there is the red marker on the map, which users can click to show the bubble with the phone address and 'more info' link though.

Comment: Well the info bubble would preclude static maps then.